# function returns address of local variable warning in C confusion

Tags: c

I have written a C program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *call()
{
    int *a, b;
    b = 43;
    a = &b;
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    p = call();
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

I had this observation that we should not pass address of local pointer, or local variable's address. I compiled my program with this

```
gcc -Wall -W 1.c -o 1
```

I didn't see any warning.Now,I changed my program a little

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *call()
{
    int b;
    b = 43;
    return &b;//local variable's address
}

int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    p = call();
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled with same gcc command,

```
gcc -Wall -W 1.c -o 1
```

I get a warning

```
 warning: function returns address of local variable
```

Why this warning was not present in the first case?

Comment: In first case you are returning value store in the memory referenced by 'a', compiler while executing 'return a;' doesn't know anything about the memory pointed by 'a'(whether it is dynamically allocated or local variable or global variable).

Comment: how compiler do not know. The pointer is clearly defined locally. There is no malloc call too. So why its a problem.

Comment: *Can* the compiler know? Yes, it can if the compiler writers decided to handle that case. The `gcc` authors decided not to. The compiler can't (and doesn't claim to) pick up all logic errors so it's a balance between more code in the compiler to pick up more errors versus keeping the code less complex. If you like, have a look at the gcc code and see if you can work out how to add the code to detect this case. I think you'll quickly find it is not as simple as it looks.

Comment: Yes it is easy to detect local variable case, rather than pointer.

Comment: The problem is compilers store as little data a possible.  When processing a function it knows what the local values are. But it doesn't track where it got its value. In the second example it knows on that line that the value is local. But in the first example it has forgotten where the a got its value. In this case its "easy" you only have to store one level of indirection. But what if we added 10 or 1000 variable each assigned to the one before? How many levels should the compiler track?

Comment: clang does a little bit better job on tasks like this. clang --analyze actually catches this error.